# React axios post request not allowing user to add to favorite movie

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I'm currently building a Netlfix mockup app, part of its functionality allows users to add to their favorite movie list. However, I keep getting this POST error 500 status from Axios whenever I click on the add favorite movie button.

I've tried everything even checked my API to see if there as issue with my POST request but to no avail.

**So my question is**, *how can I fix this issue?*

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

**Code**

```js
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import axios from "axios";

import {
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import {
  Button,
  Container,
  Row,
  Col
} from "react-bootstrap";

import "./movie-view.scss";

export class MovieView extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      movies: [],
      user: null,
    };
  }

  addMovie(movie, user) {
    let username = localStorage.getItem("user");
    let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    console.log(movie);
    console.log(token);

    axios
      .post(
        `https://mymoviesapi2023.herokuapp.com/users/${username}/movies/${movie._id}`, {}, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
          }
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        alert(`${movie.Title} has been added from your list.`);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  delFavMovie = (movie, user) => {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    let username = localStorage.getItem("user");
    console.log(movie);
    console.log(token);
    axios
      .delete(
        `https://mymoviesapi2023.herokuapp.com/users/${username}/movies/${movie._id}`, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
          },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        alert(`${movie.Title} has been removed from your list.`);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("Error");
      });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      movie,
      user,
      onBackClick
    } = this.props;

    return ( <
      Container className = "movie-view" >
      <
      Row >
      <
      Col className = "movie-poster" >
      <
      img src = {
        movie.ImageURL
      }
      /> <
      /Col> <
      /Row> <
      Row className = "movie-title" >
      <
      Col className = "label" > Title: < /Col> <
      Col className = "value" > {
        movie.Title
      } < /Col> <
      /Row> <
      Row className = "movie-description" >
      <
      Col className = "label" > Description: < /Col> <
      Col className = "value" > {
        movie.Description
      } < /Col> <
      /Row> <
      Row >
      <
      Link to = {
        `/directors/${movie.Director.Name}`
      } >
      <
      Button variant = "link" > Director < /Button> <
      /Link> <
      Link to = {
        `/genres/${movie.Genre.Name}`
      } >
      <
      Button variant = "link" > Genre < /Button> <
      /Link> <
      /Row> <
      Button

      onClick = {
        () => {
          onBackClick(null);
        }
      } >
      Back <
      /Button> <
      Button className = "button ml-2"
      onClick = {
        () => {
          this.addMovie(movie, user);
        }
      } >
      Add to favorites <
      /Button> <
      Button className = "button ml-2"
      onClick = {
        () => {
          this.delFavMovie(movie, user);
        }
      } >
      Remove from favorites <
      /Button> <
      /Container>
    );
  }
}
```

**API POST Request**

```js
// ADD MOVIE TO FAVORITES LIST OF USER
app.post('/users/:Username/movies/:MovieID',
  passport.authenticate({
    session: false
  }),
  (req, res) => {
    if (req.user.Username !== req.params.Username) {
      res.status(403).json('Not allowed to add movie to another user\'s favorites list');
    } else {
      Users.findOneAndUpdate({
          Username: req.params.Username
        },
        {
          $push: {
            FavoriteMovies: req.params.MovieID
          }
        }, {
          new: true
        }, // This line ensures that the updated document is returned
        (err, updated_User) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500).send(`Error:${err}`)
          } else {
            res.json(updated_User)
          }
        });
    }
  });
```

**Console: Axios Error**
[image]

**Logs**
[image]

Comment: Do you get any logs in the terminal when you start the server?

Comment: 500 - internal server error, it's backend problem.
Please show the server error logs.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski just checked thanks. I've edit my post to include the logs.

Comment: @LiarРonest I've included the logs

Comment: The first argument of `passport.authenticate` is supposed to be a string with a name of a strategy.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski thank you, this solved my issue. Need to look at my logs more 

Comment: Asking a stackoverflow question should be the last thing you do after tens of hours of searching results in logs and google